# AppleTV Remote Shortcut to Sleep

Tags: appletv, remote-control

I have a 2nd gen AppleTV unit. I would like to know if there is a way to use the AppleTV remote to put the unit to sleep (e.g. hold a key down)?  Currently, the only way I know to do this is to traverse the menus back out to Settings, and then select Sleep Now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold down the main centre button. Should put it to sleep after a couple of seconds.

Hit it again to wake it up.

Comment: Fantastic. I just tried this (same AppleTV) and it worked. Never knew that. Thanks Alex.